# How can inefficient SQL queries be prevented from slowing a database server

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, performance

I have an ASP .NET 4.5 application. On a maintenance page is a text box which allows administrative users to write SQL which is executed directly against the SQL Server 2008 database.

Occasionally one of the administrative users writes some inefficient SQL and the SQL Server process starts using up all the memory and CPU cycles on the server. We then have to start and stop the service to get the server responsive again.

Is there any way that I can stop these from queries consuming all the resources? These queries will not return fast enough for the user to see them so it's okay to cancel the query.

**Edit**
I realise it would be better to prevent users from writing SQL queries, but unfortunately I cannot remove this functionality from the application. The admin users don't want to be educated.

Comment: If you have the [max degree of parallelism](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189094.aspx) set to unlimited (or more than 1) you can execute all queries `MAXDOP 1` to prevent them eating all the cores.

Comment: That said, I don't know of a technical way, other than limited the CommandTimeout on the connection, or monitoring and educating those who cause these problems.

Comment: Assuming you have a production/staging setup, make the admin test the queries first on staging so that an important machine isn't tied up. Even if you kill the query after a time limit, you may tie up important resources in the meantime (not good in production).

Comment: We do encourage the admin to test queries on the staging system but we can't force them do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the query governor at the server level but not sure about a per user or per connection / application limit.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd421653.aspx

That said, it is likely a poor / dangerous practice to allow users to directly enter SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks, adding "set query_governor_cost_limit 600" to the beginning of any SQL that is entered seems to have stopped anything too wild from running without upsetting the users too much.

Answer (score 3):

First off I would make sure these queries are not locking any tables (either use NOLOCK or SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED for each query ran).

As far as resources go, I would look at something like the Resource Governor.  We use this for any adhoc reports on our production OLTP system.

Pinal Dave has a great blog entry on it.  You can also look at Technet or other MS sites for information on what it is and how to set it up.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/06/04/sql-server-simple-example-to-configure-resource-governor-introduction-to-resource-governor/

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a user which will have no more and no less privileges than necessary.
2. Create some login data to the user, you will not share this with the admins who will write the queries.
3. Create a panel/page/application where you let them write their queries. Here you can add additional constraints unavailable at RDBMS system-level.

You let your users access this panel/page/application and they will run their queries through this. If they are doing anything undesired uncovered by you, then you just issue your modifications for the privilege and the panel/page/application.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the pros/cons of allowing users to construct and run their own queries, one solution could be to use the Resource Governor that comes with SQL 2008/2012. I think it's only available in Enterprise editions which might mean you can't use it (you haven't specified an edition in your question).

[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) has an article on how to manage workloads, but basically you can limit a session (based on login details or any other decernible information) to only use a certain % of CPU and/or memory.

Answer (score -1):

Best way to prevent SQL from using memory/CPU: don't let users run queries.

SQL Server is supposed to use all the memory it can get it hands on, so the memory usage (or the CPU usage for that matter) wouldn't be reason to restart SQL.

By default .NET SqlCommand timeout is 30 seconds. When it times out the query will be canceled. Queries can take a while to cancel, especially if you were making a data modification and rollbacks have to occur. It's possible while the query is running/canceling other user queries are being blocked. This might make it seem like the SQL Server is unresponsive, but eventually it will finish up and your CPU usage will go back to normal. The memory however will continue to be consumed by the SQL Server process.

Comment: What is the purpose of a database if nobody can access it?